# Could reference be used when passing para in template overload?

Tags: c++, templates, reference, lifetime

I am reading the book of *C++ Templates The Complete Guide - second edition*. In **chapter 1.5**, the author gives a simple example to explain when passing para through template overload, reference should be avoided:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

template < typename T>
T const& max(T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return b < a ? a : b;
}

char const* max(char const* a, char const* b)
{
    return std::strcmp(b, a) < 0 ? a : b;
}

template < typename T>
T const& max(T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
    return max(max(a, b), c);
}

int main()
{
    auto m1 = ::max(7, 42, 68); // OK

    char const* s1 = "frederic";
    char const* s2 = "anica";
    char const* s3 = "lucas";
    auto m2 = ::max(s1, s2, s3); // undefined behaviour
}
```

When called `::max(s1, s2, s3)`, undefined behaviour may occur, and emphasize that this error could be very subtle, and not must-see. What he explains is `max(a,b)` creates a new temporary varirable, and destroyed after max's return, what makes a dangling reference.

But I could not understand that clearly, if `max(s1,s2)` inside `max(s1,s2,s3)` is called, isn't `max(s1,s2)`'s returned value points to actual `s1` in `main`? Where does the new temporary varirable come from?
And could you detailed show me the complete process when I called `max(s1,s2,s3)`?

Comment: `max(s1, s2)` returns `s1` by value (`char const*`), not by reference (`char const*&`).

Comment: *"author gives a simple example to explain when passing para through template overload, reference should be avoided"* Can you add a quote from the book?

Comment: The confusion may due to making a distinction between pointers and objects. Pointers point to objects, but they are also objects themselves. The problem with the example is.`max` returns temporary copies of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

`char const* max(char const* a, char const* b)` returns by value, aka returns a temporary object.

In `return max(max(a, b), c);`, both calls return temporary pointers (if `T` is `const char *`), which die at the end of this line.

`T const& max(T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)` then returns a reference to such temporary pointer, which becomes dangling immediately.

Note that those pointers themselves being temporaries is unrelated to them pointing to non-temporary strings.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very subtle, and to understand it, we need to look inside `max(s1, s2, s3)`:

```cpp
// the compiler instantiates a function along these lines
char const* const& max(char const* const& a, // a, b, c, refer to the pointers in main
                       char const* const& b,
                       char const* const& c)
{
    // call to the overload of max for char const*, not to the max function template
    return max(max(a, b), c);
}
```

At this point, `max(a, b)` and then `max(..., c)` are called with two pointers by value.
The `max` overload for pointers also returns a pointer by value.
However, the function template returns a `const&`, so we actually return a reference to a temporary pointer. `const&` results in temporary materialization when it binds to temporary objects, so contrary to intuition, returning a temporary object as a reference compiles.

It's as if we had written:

```cpp
char const* tmp = max(max(a,, b), c);
return tmp; // return reference to local object => reference is immediately invalid
```

The result is then used like this:

```cpp
auto m2 = ::max(s1, s2, s3);
```

Because `m2` is an object and not a reference, the result of `::max` gets copied. The result of `::max` is an invalid reference, and accessing it is undefined behavior.

#### The underlying issue

The underlying issue is mixing objects and (const) references. If references were used everywhere, this code would be safer. If objects were used everywhere, the code would be even safer.

Functions which pass through const references are inherently unsafe in C++. The problem isn't limited to templates, although templates can make it harder to spot:

```cpp
std::string const& max(std::string const& a, std::string const& b);

// thanks to temporary materialization,
// this call creates two temporary std::string objects
auto const& c = max("a", "b"); // c is a dangling reference
```

`const&` can bind to temporary objects, and the language doesn't protect you from shooting yourself in the foot by creating invalid references with this.
The easiest way to reproduce the problem is:

```cpp
int const& get() {
    return 0;
}
```

#### Language evolution

User [@BrianBi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481267/brian-bi) has submitted a proposal for C++26 that would fix the underlying issue (in part).
See proposal [P2748 - Disallow Binding a Returned Glvalue to a Temporary](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2748r1.html).